# Can I use celery to handle the process of upload file to third-party server?

Tags: django, server, celery, virtual-machine, django-celery

Let's suppose I have a Django application which takes posts from users and uploads them to a third party storage using an API call.

Now, these users hit the server only in a particular period of time every day, let's suppose it is at 11:00 clock and upto 11:20 only. Maximum requests can be upto 3000 (min 2500) i.e in a 20 mins span 3000 POST requests will be made to the server. And with each request 5-10 mb file is getting posted to the third party storage using an API. I calculated the average time taken for this POST to API which is 5 seconds(Average). The return response from the Django view which handled this POST request is getting  halted while the file upload takes place.

Now if I set celery in such a way that when a user does a POST on server I validate that post and hand over the uploading part to celery meanwhile my Django continues with the other requests in order keep a fluid operation for user while Celery takes care of  uploading all the files one by one.

Can I do something like that?

If I can , what could be the drawbacks in it?

Will there be a situation where I may lost some file uploads?

I am new to celery and can't quite figure out how things happen in that. So, I am hoping that the community will help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i think you should handle the file upload process before the request is handled by your application. Because the file was uploaded twice in one request according you described in the post 1. the file was uploaded to your server 2. you uploaded the file to the third-party server.

Why not upload directly to a third-party server?

Comment: Yeah the file will get directly uploaded to the 3rd party server (I have edited the question).But my major concern is will I lose a file if I use celery to upload it to the 3rd party server and let Django only handle the requests.

Comment: Of cource, you can use celery for uploading the file to third-party server. but i wonder  how did you put the file from user's computer to your server?  i cannot figure out the process.

Comment: Yeah the file upload to 3rd party server only happens when we do model_object.save() . So, I am planning to send the model_object to celery where it can perform save operation on it.

Comment: the binary data of the file already upload to your server when you call model_object.save(). And you should avoid the process

Comment: Can you help me in figuring out how to handle the file uploads separately from the Django requests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235833/discussion-between-archzi-and-pinjarla-girish).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is

1. upload the file in the web page through the js logic, then the third-party file server will return you an id(or url )  of the file data.
2. then you post the data with the file url to your application and save it.

i recommand you not use celery to handle the process of file uploading

cause if you introduce Celery, you need a broker( save the message eg: RabbitMQ or else), and the process of handle request will separately two sub-process. the one of process was handled synchronized and the other was handled asynchronously. And you cannot maintain data consistency without other tools

Comment: Yes, uploading using JS looks like a possible solution . Thank you for the thought. I will see if my storage API can be accessed using JS and comment back.

Comment: Uploading using Javascript is an option, but it is making my API credentials public, which some users can take advantage of and change the contents inside it.

Comment: @PinjarlaGirish security issues can be solved in many ways。like ACL